# Is there a simple audio player that can be remote controlled with UDP or TCP commands?

Tags: audio, tcp, remote-control, udp

Is there a simple audio player that can be remote controlled with UDP or TCP commands?

The control needed is very simple:

- Stop
- Play
- Pause
- Volume up
- Volume down
- Next Track
- Previous Track

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Scott Chamberlain answer, I tried VLC Media Player.
I've found the RC interface as an easy method to get a remote control over TCP.

(I wrote a [blog post](http://msdevs.blogspot.co.il/2014/06/remote-control-vlc-media-player-over-tcp.html) and made a short video demonstration on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cPUsR5qOAEw))

It goes like this:

> 1. Open your command line (cmd) and cd to VLC install location.
> 2. Type the following command:
>      **vlc --intf rc --rc-host localhost:50000**
>      (Port doesn't have to be 50000)
> 3. Open [Socket Test](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sockettest/) TCP client or any other TCP client.
> 4. Connect to 127.0.0.1:50000
> 5. Send "Help" to get a list of available commands.

The commands are:

```
+----[ Remote control commands ]
|
| add XYZ  . . . . . . . . . . . . add XYZ to playlist
| enqueue XYZ  . . . . . . . . . queue XYZ to playlist
| playlist . . . . .  show items currently in playlist
| play . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . play stream
| stop . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . stop stream
| next . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  next playlist item
| prev . . . . . . . . . . . .  previous playlist item
| goto . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  goto item at index
| repeat [on|off] . . . .  toggle playlist item repeat
| loop [on|off] . . . . . . . . . toggle playlist loop
| random [on|off] . . . . . . .  toggle random jumping
| clear . . . . . . . . . . . . . . clear the playlist
| status . . . . . . . . . . . current playlist status
| title [X]  . . . . . . set/get title in current item
| title_n  . . . . . . . .  next title in current item
| title_p  . . . . . .  previous title in current item
| chapter [X]  . . . . set/get chapter in current item
| chapter_n  . . . . . .  next chapter in current item
| chapter_p  . . . .  previous chapter in current item
|
| seek X . . . seek in seconds, for instance `seek 12'
| pause  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  toggle pause
| fastforward  . . . . . . . .  .  set to maximum rate
| rewind  . . . . . . . . . . . .  set to minimum rate
| faster . . . . . . . . . .  faster playing of stream
| slower . . . . . . . . . .  slower playing of stream
| normal . . . . . . . . . .  normal playing of stream
| frame. . . . . . . . . .  play frame by frame
| f [on|off] . . . . . . . . . . . . toggle fullscreen
| info . . . . .  information about the current stream
| stats  . . . . . . . .  show statistical information
| get_time . . seconds elapsed since stream's beginning
| is_playing . . . .  1 if a stream plays, 0 otherwise
| get_title . . . . .  the title of the current stream
| get_length . . . .  the length of the current stream
|
| volume [X] . . . . . . . . . .  set/get audio volume
| volup [X]  . . . . . . .  raise audio volume X steps
| voldown [X]  . . . . . .  lower audio volume X steps
| adev [device]  . . . . . . . .  set/get audio device
| achan [X]. . . . . . . . . .  set/get audio channels
| atrack [X] . . . . . . . . . . . set/get audio track
| vtrack [X] . . . . . . . . . . . set/get video track
| vratio [X]  . . . . . . . set/get video aspect ratio
| vcrop [X]  . . . . . . . . . . .  set/get video crop
| vzoom [X]  . . . . . . . . . . .  set/get video zoom
| snapshot . . . . . . . . . . . . take video snapshot
| strack [X] . . . . . . . . .  set/get subtitle track
| key [hotkey name] . . . . . .  simulate hotkey press
| menu . . [on|off|up|down|left|right|select] use menu
|
| help . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . this help message
| logout . . . . . . .  exit (if in socket connection)
| quit . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  quit vlc
|
+----[ end of help ]
```

Comment: You can also use your browser for controlling. Try `firefox 127.0.0.1:50000`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, VLC can be controlled via telnet. Which is just TCP packets sending very basic ASCII encoded data. It would not be hard to write your own program to control it.

[image]

[image]

I have never used it so I don't know the actual commands to use once you log in via telnet.

Comment: Is that available through a plugin? I have the current VLC Version, 2.1.3, and Telnet is not available in the Control interfaces.

Comment: @private_meta It must have been removed, I am on 1.1.1 and it is included by default.

Comment: There is a "Telnet" section in the Lua Main Interface, maybe it's been moved to there, not sure how that would work though.